# ngModel twoway binding keeps giving issues. How can I bind to a property so as to update an api link?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am trying to use two way binding to change the link to an API so that when I click a button and the associated value attribute of the button is used as part of the string to the API endpoint.

I went to the Hero Angular App and use the example there but @Input and @output keeps giving the same issues.

Can anyone give me a clear example with no sugar of how I could accomplish this ?

I have 2 components the AppComponent and then another component called InfoComponent.

In the AppComponent

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
<button value="for_api">button</button>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
apiFeed = "string_for_link"
}
```

Then the Info Component that comes through the Router Outlet (nvm the RouterLink)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { size } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info.component.css']
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {

  }


  ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('redacted_for_privacy' + **api_feed**).subscribe(infos => {this.infosData = [infos as any];});
}
}
```

I have tried different implementation of two-way binding and nothing works for me. I'm a bit new.

I would like when the button in the AppComponent is clicked that it's value is bound to **api_feed** and then that var is used in the Info Component to update the link to the API.

Please Help.

There should be something straight forward about this. Please show.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Child html

```
<button (click)="query.emit('foo')">Do Foo</button> <br>
<button (click)="query.emit('bar')">Do Bar</button>
```

Child TS

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './info.component.html'
})
export class InfoComponent {
  @Output() query = new EventEmitter()
}
```

Parent HTML

```
<app-info (query)="handleClick($event)"></app-info>
```

Parent TS

```
handleClick(event: any) {
    console.log(`https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint?q=${event}`)
}
```

Comment: **app-info** is the component sent through the **Router Outlet**. The Button is in the **AppComponent** component that houses the **Router Outlet**.